# Rails 3.2 Rendering Associated Models in Same Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, polymorphism, models

i'm working through Hartl. Ive got to the microposts section in Chapter 10, but instead of microposts I have introduced Hotels, and now I want to add them to a separate address model, like in [this tutorial](http://kconrails.com/2010/10/19/common-addresses-using-polymorphism-and-nested-attributes-in-rails/). I am having some trouble - my view field does not appear to enter the address

```
<%= form_for(@hotel) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "New hotel title..." %>
    <%= f.text_area :room_description, placeholder: "About room..." %>
    <%= f.text_field :price, placeholder: "Price?" %>
    <%= f.check_box :include_breakfast%>
    <%= f.label "Include breakfast?", class: "checkbox inline" %>
<br><% ["1 star", "2 star", "3 star", "4 star", "5 star"].each do |item| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :star_rate_hotel, item %> <%= item %><br />
<% end %>
<% f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
    <%= f.text_field :street, placeholder: "Street-address..." %>
    <%= f.text_field :extended, placeholder: "Extended-address..." %>
    <%= f.text_field :locality, placeholder: "Locality..." %>
    <%= f.text_field :region, placeholder: "Region..." %>
    <%= f.text_field :country, placeholder: "Country..." %>
<% end %>
<p> Upload photo hotel(optionaly)
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>
  <p>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My hotel_controller.rb

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy

  def create
    @hotel = current_user.hotels.build(params[:hotel])
    @hotel.build_address
    if @hotel.save
      flash[:success]="Hotel created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @hotel.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

  def correct_user
    @hotel = current_user.hotels.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @hotel.nil?
  end

end
```

My user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :index, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: :destroy

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @hotels = @user.hotels.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
end

  def new
    if signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
    @user = User.new
  end
  end

  def create
    if signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success]="Welcome to the Hotel Advisor!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
    end
  end

  def  edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7)
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    if (current_user == user) && (current_user.admin?)
      flash[:error] = "Can not delete own admin account!"
    else
      user.destroy
    flash[:success]="User destroyed"
  end
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def  admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
      end

end
```

My question is: how do I display addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your associated addresses in your new method, to create the associations at the same time as the new object is created. (to be more precise, just after the object is created).

Check the excelent Railscasts on that matter [Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) [Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).